# Didn't get full data from XML

Tags: php, html

I am using simplexml_load_file function for fetching data through XML. I need to get web_remarks data. If i use file_get_contents then this data is showing in inspect element.

```
[Web_Remarks] => SimpleXMLElement Object


                   (
                    )
```

I have tried both functions.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1327&pid=8782&acc=8781');

$result = file_get_contents('http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1327&pid=8782&acc=8781');
```

I just need to get this web_remarks data. Thank You

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not return an array, nor object, it returns a string of the resulting request. What do you do with `$result`?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to handle XML responses in PHP is IMHO to convert it to an array. You would either use `simplexml_load_file($path)` or a combination of `file_get_contents($path)` and `simplexml_load_string($content)`. I prefer the latter as this first downloads the content and if errors occur still allows me to use the returned content. If valid XML was returned, an easy conversion is to use a slight detour by converting it to JSON and then decoding it. After that it's a simple array that you can use:

```
<?php
$file= 'http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1327&pid=8782&acc=8781';

$fileContent= file_get_contents($file);
try {
    $xml= simplexml_load_string($fileContent);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

    print "<h2>Sample output</h3>".
      "Ad Type of Item 1 in 'Listing': " . $array["Listing"][0]["Ad_Type"]."<br />".
      "Title: <i>" . $array["Listing"][0]["Property_Title"]."</i><br />";


} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print "An exception occurred: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

This would give me the following output on my machine:

[image: Sample output]